# Removing sublists of empty entries from a list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I've got a list that looks like this:

```
some_list = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h'], ['', '', '', '']]
```

I want to remove all empty sublists within the list, so that the product is just

```
clean_list = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h']]
```

I've tried the following

```
for x in some_list:
    if x == ['', '', '', '']:
        some_list.remove(x)
```

and

```
clean_list = filter(None, list)
```

and

```
clean_list = [x for x in list if x]
```

but I keep getting an output with sublists with empty entries. Thoughts?

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable, that masks the built-in type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`any()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) to *select* lists with non-empty values:

```
clean_list = [sublist for sublist in some_list if any(sublist)]
```

`any()` short-circuits; iterating over the values in `sublist` it'll return `True` as soon as it finds a true (non-empty) string in that sublist, and only returns `False` after testing all values, finding them to be empty.

Your `x == ['', '', '', '']` loop failed because you were modifying a list while iterating over it. As the list gets shorter, iteration starts skipping later elements as they have shifted indices, see [strange result when removing item from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260089/strange-result-when-removing-item-from-a-list) for more detail.

Your `filter(None, ..)` attempt fails because `['', '', '', '']` is itself *not a false value*, it is a non-empty list, there are 4 strings in it. It doesn't matter that those strings are empty. The same applies to your list comprehension; all lists in `some_list` are non-empty, so all are considered *true*.

Comment: Thank you for the beautiful response, I learned a lot from what seems to be such a simple problem.

Comment: `filter(any, some_list)`